# Decoding output of Adobe Flex Base64encoder with C++

Tags: c++, apache-flex, base64, decode, rfc

I've developed web services in C++ and have implemented the ability to provide a base 64 encoded string to send files with other meta data. While I have successfully decoded the string when the encoded data is a text file, images and other binary files are not decoding correctly.

Can you point me to a C++ library or implementation of base64 decode that works with Adobe Flex Base64encoder?  What RFC does the Flex encode/decode implement?

Answer (score 0):

For those with the same issue:

Set "encoder.useNewLines = false" in Flex and use the base64 library at http://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/.